# Searching tool/guide to read a 1998 file with "magic number" SFS

Tags: parsing, file-type

I have a file which starts with magic number "SFS". This file were created in 1998.
Do you have any idea to help me to parse it ?

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that the first three bytes of the file are `0x534653`?  What extension (if any) does the file have?

Comment: Yes. And the extension of the file is _x_

Comment: Can you provide any more detail?  File size?  Any ASCII content?

Comment: File is here : http://sdrv.ms/KFgS9p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bytes 35 through to 70 of your file read `Copyright (c) 1996 Auric Vision Ltd`.  A quick Google reveals Auric Vision Ltd (together with Zes't Studio) to be the developer of an Adult adventure game called [ГЭГ: Отвязное приключение](http://www.mobygames.com/game/gag-otvjaznoe-prikluchenie) (or *Gag: Het Impotentie-Mysterie* in Dutch), of which one component was a Tetris-clone.  Your file is one of the two in [this download](http://www.download-central.ws/Win32/Tetris/XTET/) of that component.

If you still wish to 'parse' the file, you will need to reverse-engineer the executable (which may be a violation of Auric Vision's license conditions).

Comment: To your point of view is not a common file format ? I know about potentials illegal aspects of what I try to do

Comment: @gsempe: Without seeing the source/reverse-engineering the executable, it's impossible to be 100% *certain* that the file isn't a "common" format; however, in support of that view, I would point out that: (1) the program does not *appear* to exchange data with others, so there would be no particular motive for using a "common" format; (2) the program was developed in 1996, when proprietary file formats were extremely prevalent in Windows; (3) the executable does not make use of any library calls that would suggest use of a "common" file format; and (4) extensive searching has yielded nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll probably load it in win95 current june.